# Broken Python install: "raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace) ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available"

Tags: python, gtk

I'm not sure exactly how I did it, but I think I broke my Python-GTK interface.  I don't seem to be able to get applications written in Python using GTK libraries to run.  Here is an example of three of them, gnome-tweaks, guake, and deluge-gtk:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HvpXYp2Xcf/

I'm sure more information is needed but I'm not entirely sure what to provide that isn't in the paste...

```
$ which python && python -V && which python3 && python3 -V
/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.17
/usr/local/bin/python3
Python 3.8.2

$ ldd `which netstat`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe29bd5000)
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x00007f17b88b5000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f17b868d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f17b829c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f17b8098000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f17b7e79000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f17b7c07000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f17b8ce3000)

$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ find /lib -iname 'libc*.so'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn-2.27.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcidn-2.27.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so

$ gapplication version; gio --version; glib-compile-resources --version; glib-compile-schemas --version; gsettings --version; gtester --version; gtester-report --version; 
2.65.0
2.65.0
2.65.0
2.65.0
2.65.0
gtester version 2.65.0
gtester-report (GLib utils) version 2.65.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

removed the following files from `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  480638 Apr 15 13:37 libgirepository-1.0.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      30 Apr 15 13:43 libgirepository-1.0.so -> ./libgirepository-1.0.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      30 Apr 15 13:43 libgirepository-1.0.so.1 -> ./libgirepository-1.0.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  212456 Apr 15 13:41 libgirepository-1.0.so.1.0.0
```

and guake launched.  Replaced them with the files from `/usr/lib/local/x86_64-linux-gnu` and set up symbolic links.

Not sure how/why these were corrupted but it seems to have solved the problem.

It seems that the point source of the problem is here:

```
pwd: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x
root@computer# ./libgirepository-1.0.so.1.0.0 --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```